# How to make grid items ignore each others heights when one has more content

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, tailwind-css, css-grid

I'm making a notes app and currently having trouble with my grid layout using TailwindCSS.

This is how it currently looks when the overflowing content is hidden. Each note has a fixed height of 120px, then becomes auto once the show more is clicked.

[grid before expanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJ1jw.png)

This is what it looks like when the show more has been clicked. The other items in the row also get expanded.

[grid after expanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxhZF.png)

This is what my grid container looks like:

```
            <ul className="grid md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 grid-cols-1 gap-4 my-16">
              {notes.map((note) => (
                <div
                  key={note._id}
                  id={note._id}
                  className="border rounded p-4 flex flex-col"
                >
                  <Note
                    title={note.title}
                    id={note._id}
                    content={note.content}
                    createdAt={note.createdAt}
                    updatedAt={note.updatedAt}
                    deleteNote={deleteNote}
                    accessToken={cookies.access_token}
                    fetchNotes={fetchNotes}
                  />
                </div>
              ))}
            </ul>
```

and each note item:

```
        <div className="">
          <div className="flex justify-between">
            <li className="font-bold text-2xl">{title}</li>
            <div className="flex gap-4">
              <button onClick={toggleEdit}>
                <FaTrash />
              </button>
              <button onClick={toggleEdit}>
                <FaPencil />
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <li
            ref={contentRef}
            className={` max-h-auto mt-8 whitespace-pre-line ${
              isShowMore
                ? "h-auto overflow-y-auto"
                : "h-[120px] overflow-y-hidden"
            } `}
          >
            {content}
          </li>
          {isOverflowing && (
            <button
              className="text-sm mb-8 mt-2 text-blue-800"
              onClick={() => setIsShowMore(!isShowMore)}
            >
              {isShowMore ? "Show Less" : "Show More"}
            </button>
          )}
          <li>{createdAt.toString().split("T")[0]}</li>
        </div>
```

Is there an extra class I'm missing somewhere ? or should this be done with flex?

I've tried converting it to a flex layout but it still seems to do the same thing.

Comment: You can't. Or it wouldn't be a grid.

Comment: Flex is better if you want different heights. The default is `stretch`, but you can change to `flex-start` etc.